# Unable to mock os name with Python on Windows

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

I have the following method:

```py
class Controls:

    def check_os(self) -> None:

        if os.name != "posix":
            raise OSError
```

I'm trying to test it like this:

```py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def name_mock(mocker):
    return mocker.patch("path_to_module.controls.os.name", return_value="posix")

def test_check_os_fail(name_mock):
    controls = Controls()
    controls.check_os()
```

But then the following error is raised:

```
platform win32 -- Python 3.9.0, pytest-6.2.2, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
plugins: cov-2.11.1, mock-3.5.1  
collected 57 items / 56 deselected / 1 selected

tests\test_controls.py 
INTERNALERROR> Traceback (most recent call last):
...
NotImplementedError: cannot instantiate 'PosixPath' on your system
```

What is happening exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening here is that `pytest` internally uses a `pathlib.Path` object, which upon initialization asks for `os.name` to define which `Path` implementation to use. There are two internal implementations for `Path`, `PosixPath` and `WindowsPath`, which are only available under the respective systems. As you are faking a Posix system by patching `os.name`, it tries to instantiate a `PosixPath` object, which is not defined under Windows.

What you can do in this case is to wrap `os.name` in your own function, e.g. something like:

```py
import os

def os_name():
    return os.name

class Controls:
    def check_os(self) -> None:
        if os_name != "posix":
            raise OSError
```

and patch that function in your test:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def name_mock(mocker):
    return mocker.patch("path_to_module.controls.os_name", return_value="posix")
```

This way you only patch the call you are supposed to patch, without affecting other code that also uses `os.name`.